# Relation between mean field critical point and RG critical point

Tags: statistical-mechanics, renormalization, critical-phenomena, mean-field-theory

In the mean field / Landau picture a critical point is where the potential of the order parameter changes curvature. E.g. the mean field potential of a scalar $\phi^4$ theory is
$$\mathcal{L} = a t \eta^2+\frac12b\eta^4-H\eta$$
with $t=(T-T_c)/T_c$ and $b>0$.

At $H=0$ and $T=T_c$ the second order term changes sign and the position of the order parameter minimum, indicating the phase in which our system is, changes. For $H \neq 0$ the potential tilts a bit.

In contrast, in the RG picture a critical point is defined as a fixed point of the RG flow which has codimension $2$ and  the correlation length becomes infinite $\xi=\infty$.

I have a little problem tying these two pictures together. Some questions are

- Does every critical point of mean field survive in the RG picture? E.g. are there theories which don't exhibit critical point in the full RG treatment but do in their mean field approximations. What does this mean?
- My fixed points in the RG flow will change value and some might vanish or new ones will appear depending on what couplings I allow to appear in the Hamiltonian. How do I know that I am including all the right couplings?

Comment: You might want to split up the questions. I really like your "Are there theories which don't exhibit critical points in the full RG treatment but do in the mean field approximations?" I've come across theories whose phase transitions are only continuous in the mean field approximation, and first order otherwise, which, though it doesn't answer the question, might be interesting to think about.